# I am the Manager/owner of a Michigan LLC and need to take legal action in Michigan to collect unpaid tenant rent

Tags: rental-property, landlord, small-claims-court, limited-liability-company

I am the Manager/owner of a Michigan  LLC which owns several rental properties. I need to take legal action in Michigan to collect unpaid tenant rent... about $8000 overdue

Do I have to hire an attorney or can I file directly as Manager/owner  of the LLC?

Does anyone know any specific statute and/or case that applies here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not legally *required* to hire an attorney, you are allowed to do it yourself. However, if you didn't already know that or could not figure it out, then the chances are very slim that you could do it correctly on your own. Effectively, you have to hire an attorney. And we certainly can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: I have done it several times with properties owned by myself only and in several states... I'm being told locally by an attorney that i can't... won't be the first time an attorney has told me something that is just  plain false...so, too, a judge.. I am looking for case plus statute here. Anyone have some legal facts to get on record if necessary. Are you an attorney ??? If so, then please give me a full answers.